# How can I sort this map of components? react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand how to sort in javascript insularly, but I used a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMfcEsySPEw) to create this list of notes component & I don't know where to sort without interfering with map.

I haven't tried much, I just can't imagine where to sort by renderDate(date)

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

import "./plan-list.css";

function renderDate(date) {
  let d = dayjs(date);
  return d.format("MMMM D YYYY, HH:mm");
}

const Note = ({ note: { _id, title, body, updatedAt, date } }) => (
  <Link to={`/notes/${_id}`}>
    <div className="notes-list-item">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <span className="notes-list-date">{renderDate(date)}</span>
    </div>
  </Link>
);

export default ({ notes }) => (
  <div className="notes-list">
    {notes.map(none => (
      <Note note={none} key={`note-${none._id}`} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

something like [this](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-property-javascript/), but where?

```
notes.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.date > b.date) ? 1 : -1
})
```

```
notes.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.{renderDate(date)} > b.{renderDate(date)}) ? 1 : -1
})
```

Comment: sort is chain method so you can do it directly in the render: notes.sort(...).map(...)

Comment: oh sweet that was easy thanks Satif!

Comment: Just be aware that you are going to do that sort during each re-render. If there are only a couple, NBD. If notes are being passed as props, you could sort them once when they change and keep that in your React state for the form.

Comment: ok. this component is where they are listed, the other components from the tutorial add to or delete a note from the list. sort in other components?  I'll keep this in mind nonetheless thanks jalynn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort and create your elements

```
export default ({ notes }) => (
  <div className="notes-list">
    {notes.sort((a, b) => { return (a.date > b.date) ? 1 : -1 }).map(none => (
      <Note note={none} key={`note-${none._id}`} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```